# Not showing the images when the activity called

Tags: android

I have a Fragment Activity and in the `onCreate` method includes the following code;

```
    newListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_listView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    id = intent.getStringExtra("id");

    databaseAdapter = new DataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    databaseAdapter = databaseAdapter.open();

    String[] new_list = databaseAdapter.getNewByID(id);

    NewAdapter madapter = new NewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), new_list);
    newListView.setAdapter(madapter);
```

**databaseAdapter** works fine.(when I debug shows the image urls). `new_list` has list of image urls.

**NewAdapter** class is shown below;

```
public class NewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    String [] images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public NewAdapter(Context context,String [] images) {
        super(context,R.layout.new_cell);
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_cell, null);
        }

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.new_imageView);

        imageLoader.displayImage(images[position],image);
        return convertView;
    }
```

When I run the code and open the activity, Images are not showing. Please help me with this.

Comment: initialize `imageLoader` before using in on create.

Comment: @SohailZahid  Adapter class does not have `oncreate`

Comment: you can initialize it in activity on create methods in which class you use this listview or you can initialize it Adapter constructor `public NewAdapter(Context context,String [] images) {
        super(context,R.layout.new_cell);
        this.images = images;  ....// here
    }`

Comment: @SohailZahid please can you post with more details

Comment: ok just tell me which image loader you are using Universal image loader ....?

Comment: @SohailZahid yes.It is.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a one new line in Adapter constructor.

```
public NewAdapter(Context context,String [] images) {
    super(context,R.layout.new_cell);
    this.images = images;
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

    //initImageLoader(context);
}
```

Custom initiliazation use below call once before using ImageLoader.

```
public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP

        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .showImageOnFail(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).resetViewBeforeLoading()
                .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                context)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    }
```

Comment: imageLoader shows "cannot reslove symbol 'imageLoader'"

Comment: sorry i have pasted worng line repalce with this one `ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));`

Comment: @tenten still have issue ?